# optimize python key-searching in hierarchichal dictionary

Tags: python, optimization, dictionary, defaultdict

I am trying to optimize my code since when I try to load huge dictionaries it becomes really slow. I think It's because it searchs for a key in the dictionary. I've been reading about python `defaultdict` and I think it might be a good improvement but I fail to implement it here. As you can see is a hierarchichal dictionary structure. Any hint will be appreciated.

```
class Species:
    '''This structure contains all the information needed for all genes.
    One specie have several genes, one gene several proteins'''
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name #name of the GENE
        self.genes = {}
    def addProtein(self, gene, protname, len):
        #Converting a line from the input file into a protein and/or an exon
        if gene in self.genes:
            #Gene in the structure
            self.genes[gene].proteins[protname] = Protein(protname, len)
            self.genes[gene].updateProts()
        else:
            self.genes[gene] = Gene(gene) 
            self.updateNgenes()
            self.genes[gene].proteins[protname] = Protein(protname, len)
            self.genes[gene].updateProts()
    def updateNgenes(self):
    #Updating the number of genes
        self.ngenes = len(self.genes.keys())
```

The definitions of gene and Protein are:

```
class Protein:
    #The class protein contains information about the length of the protein and a list with it's exons (with it's own attributes)
    def __init__(self, name, len):
        self.name = name
        self.len = len

class Gene:
    #The class gene contains information about the gene and a dict with it's proteins (with it's own attributes)
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.proteins = {}
        self.updateProts()
    def updateProts(self):
        #Update number of proteins
        self.nproteins = len(self.proteins)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a `defaultdict` because your `__init__` methods require arguments.

This is probably one of your bottlenecks:

```
def updateNgenes(self):
#Updating the number of genes
    self.ngenes = len(self.genes.keys())
```

`len(self.genes.keys())` creates a `list` of all keys before calculating length.  This means that *every time* you add a gene, you create a list and throw it away.  This list creation gets more and more expensive the more genes you have.  To avoid creating an intermediate list, just do `len(self.genes)`.

Better yet would be to make `ngenes` a [property](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) so it is only calculated when you need it.

```
@property
def ngenes(self):
    return len(self.genes)
```

The same can be done with `nproteins` in the `Gene` class.

Here is your code refactored:

```
class Species:
    '''This structure contains all the information needed for all genes.
    One specie have several genes, one gene several proteins'''

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name #name of the GENE
        self.genes = {}

    def addProtein(self, gene, protname, len):
        #Converting a line from the input file into a protein and/or an exon
        if gene not in self.genes:
            self.genes[gene] = Gene(gene) 
        self.genes[gene].proteins[protname] = Protein(protname, len)

    @property
    def ngenes(self):
        return len(self.genes)

class Protein:
    #The class protein contains information about the length of the protein and a list with it's exons (with it's own attributes)
    def __init__(self, name, len):
        self.name = name
        self.len = len

class Gene:
    #The class gene contains information about the gene and a dict with it's proteins (with it's own attributes)
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.proteins = {}

    @property
    def nproteins(self):
        return len(self.proteins)
```

Comment: Or even `def __init__(): self.ngenes = 0` followed by `def addProtein(): self.ngenes += 1`, depending on how often ngenes is actually accessed. If it's hit continually like `while myspecies.ngenes < limit: ...`, that may be faster.

Comment: Now it's orders of magnitude faster and I've learned a couple of tricks. Thanks!